# Error: mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\event' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am getting the above mentioned error when I start my XAMPP server. Second line of error says: mysql.event: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly. I have 3 events to execute. i checked the events. I have BEGIN and END statements for all events. What is the meaning of this error. Any suggestions Please.

```
[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Table '.\mysql\event' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

[Warning] Checking table:   '.\mysql\event'


[ERROR] mysql.event: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command from PhpMyAdmin to fix it for this table:

```
REPAIR TABLE event;
```

Or if more tables are broken then use following command

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -p --repair --all-databases
```

Supply password whenever prompted.

Cheers!!

Comment: tried it. Result says
`table: event    Op: repair     Msg_type: status     Msg_text: OK `
but error is still there in the mysql error log.

Comment: What is the result of `CHECK TABLE event ;` now?

Comment: `table: event  Op: check  Msg_type: status   Msg_text: OK`

Comment: Great!! It is repaired now

Comment: But i restarted XAMPP. But unfortunately it shows the same error in error log list again :(

Comment: `mysqlcheck -Ar -u root -p`